# Use Symfony validator in Method arguments

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-validator

Is there any way to apply Symfony Validator constraints to method's arguments?

Something like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class acmeClass
{
  /**
  * @param $argument
  * @Assert\Choice({"YES", "NO"})
  */
  public funciton foo($argument) 
  {
    /..  
  }
}
```

So if $argument has different value than the given choices, validation throws an exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not supported by Symfony framework.

You have 2 choices:

1). Validate before calling `foo()`:

```
$errors = $validator->validate($argument, $constraint);
if (count($errors) > 0) {
    //throw some exception?
}

$acmeClassObj->foo($argument);
```

2). Validate inside `foo()` itself:

```
class acmeClass
{
    public function foo($argument)
    {
        $errors = $validator->validate($argument, $constraint);
        if (count($errors) > 0) {
            //throw some exception?
        }

        //do something here with $argument
    }
}
```

---

Honestly I think it's better that Symfony doesn't support this. Annotations and comments in general are often overlooked by programmers when reading code and they can often be left out-of-date, resulting in harder to debug code.